# Symfony 3.3 getting stacktrace when an Exception gets thrown over the cli command (eg server:start)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

Over my Symfony 3.3 project when I run a cli command such as:

```
php ./bin/console server:start
```

Sometimes an error has been thrown eg:

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]      
  Warning: key() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given
```

So using Xdebug I will debug it, but this it can be time-consuming. So finding its stacktrace would be beneficial in order to put breakpoints to the correct places.

So how can I get the stacktrace over a "systematic" exception that gets thrown over the framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's annoying. It's a know issue of Symfony. It will be fixed as of [Symfony 3.4](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-better-console-exceptions):

Answer (score 2):

Specify a level of verbosity, with:

`php ./bin/console server:start -v`

(or `-vv`/`-vvv`)

*Reference:* [Symfony Console - Verbosity Levels](https://symfony.com/doc/2.6/components/console/introduction.html#verbosity-levels)